How to amend 2 configured taxonomy fields so the contents of the second depends on the selection in the first
Using the following code I am attempting to create a dependency between 2 taxonomy fields so that the options in the second are restricted to a subsect of it's original content.
But but I don't understand why my ajax function fails to be triggered.
I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.
<?php
    
    use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
    
    /**
     * @file
     * Primary module hooks for QuizJitsu Instructions module.
     */
    
    function quizjitsu_instructions_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    
    //function quizjitsu_instructions_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Testing');
    
      if ( isset($form['field_categories']) && isset($form['field_sub_categories']) ) {
        \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Found both categories field');
    
        $form['field_categories']['#ajax'] = [
          'callback' => 'my_module_update_subcategories',
          'wrapper' => 'edit-field-sub-categories-wrapper',
        ];
    
        // Optionally, make the Sub-Categories field hidden initially
        \Drupal::messenger()->addStatus('Hook-Form-Alter successfully completed!');
        \Drupal::logger('quizjitsu')->notice('<pre>' . print_r($form['field_categories'], TRUE) . '</pre>');
      } else {
        \Drupal::messenger()->addError('Unable to find one or both fields');
      }
    
    }
    
    function my_module_update_subcategories(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      \Drupal::logger('quizjitsu')->notice('AJAX callback triggered.');
      return $form['field_sub_categories'];
    }



You're attaching to the wrong element - look further down $form['field_categories'], you'll have something like $form['field_categories']['widget'][0]['tid'], i.e. the element with #type => select. That's the element you need to attach the AJAX to

Appreciated @Clive.
